# Busy indicator not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm building an MVVM Light WPF app in Visual Studio 2015. It has a user control that contains a `WindowsFormsHost` with a `ReportViewer` for SQL Server Reporting Services local report. A button in `ReportView.xaml` calls a command, which in turn sends a message to the code-behind of `MasterListView.xaml` to generate the report.

Here's the command called by the button in `ReportViewModel.cs`:

```
public ICommand RunReportRelayCommand =>
    new RelayCommand(async ()=> { await RunReport(); });

private async Task RunReport()
{
    try
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send(true, "RunMasterListReport");
        });
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

Here's the definition of `IsBusy` property in `ReportViewModel.cs`:

```
private bool _isBusy;
public bool IsBusy
{
    get { return _isBusy; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _isBusy) return;
        _isBusy = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The same view, `ReportView.xaml`, which contains the button calling the above command also contains the following Extended WPF Toolkit Busy Indicator:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
       <DataTemplate x:Key="MasterListViewTemplate">
          <view:MasterListView />
       </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
        <StackPanel>
            <!-- Other XAML here -->
            <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MasterListViewTemplate}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator>
</UserControl>
```

Then in the `MasterListView.cs` code-behind, we have this:

```
public partial class MasterListView : UserControl
{
    public MasterListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Messenger.Default.Register<bool>(this, "RunMasterListReport", RunMasterListReport);
    }

    public async void RunMasterListReport(bool val)
    {         
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var dataSet = new DrugComplianceDataSet();
            dataSet.BeginInit();
            ReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            ReportViewer.LocalReport.ShowDetailedSubreportMessages = true;
            ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            var dataSource = new ReportDataSource
            {
                Name = "MasterListRandomDataSet",
                Value = dataSet.MasterListRandom
            };
            ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
            ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MasterListRandom.rdlc";
            dataSet.EndInit();
            var adapter = new MasterListRandomTableAdapter { ClearBeforeFill = true }
                .Fill(dataSet.MasterListRandom);
            Dispatcher.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { ReportViewer.RefreshReport(); }));
        });
    }
}
```

However, the busy indicator doesn't trigger, though the report does show after 5 seconds or so. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It is because you are only awaiting the act of sending the message, which is "instant"... your code is not going to wait for whatever event the message receipt triggers.  I would recommend getting the data in the async RunReport method and send a message with the data as a payload or something along those lines.  Upon receipt of the data, load the datasource.  Then, the await should behave as you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkW. Do you mind elaborating on your comment in an answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a whole soup of wat in there.  Things like

```
await Task.Run(() =>
```

suggest you don't really understand how async/await works.  I'd step down and find some nice documentation to read.  Also, you appear to be doing all your work on the UI thread.

```
Dispatcher.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { ReportViewer.RefreshReport(); }));
```

You shouldn't be touching a dispatcher in a background worker unless you're updating the UI.  It appears you're offloading the actual work you intend to do in a background thread (refreshing the report) on the UI thread.

Maybe your report viewer HAS to run in the UI thread.  If that's so (maybe it was designed a while ago and doesn't take advantage of multitasking) there isn't much you can do about this situation.  Your UI will be locked while it's processing.

If all your long-running work has to run on the UI thread, then strip out all that nonsense.  Before kicking off your work, update IsBusy, then offload execution of `ReportViewer.RefreshReport()` onto the Dispatcher, but using a low priority [DispatcherPriority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), so that it runs after the UI updates and shows that it is busy.  Your UI will be frozen during processing, but at least you'll give the user an indication of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, @Will. Any docs you can point me to on learning async/await better?

Comment: @Alex not any one, unfortunately.  There are a few good ones on MSDN, but they aren't in the top search hits.  I've actually got https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1449367569/ref=ox_sc_sfl_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER sitting in my cart as I'm not the happiest with my grasp of some aspects surrounding Tasks.  This book appears to be a good resource for learning about async/await.  I'm just not pulling the trigger until I get through my current read....